# Go use drop down values

Tags: html, go

I'm using the value from the drop-down list. The list I have done.

```
<form  action="/configuration" method="get">
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-center"> 
                      <div class="col-auto">
                        <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" name=select_fruit size="1" id="select_fruit">
                          <option selected>Select your fruit...</option>
                          <option value="orange">Orange</option>
                          <option value="pear">Pear</option>
                          <option value="grape">Grape</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                       <div class="col-auto">
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </form>
```

Here the handler:

```
func configuration(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "GET" {
       r.ParseForm()
       w.Write([]byte(r.Form["select_fruit"][0]))
    }
}
```

When I open the /configuration page I can see the URL (when I selected grape): http://localhost:8000/configuration?select_fruit=grape

On the configuration page, I display a text file "fruit.txt", this works (only a snippet here).

```
func ViewConfigFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data, err := config.ViewConfiguration("fruit.txt")
```

I want to change the filename (i.e. grape.txt) when I change the fruit from the dropdown. How I can set the filename as a variable from the dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stackoverflow.

When do you want the filename changed?
After submitting the form, or when changing the selected value?
If you want the second scenario, you need an async call from your client.

In both way you have to be careful; never trust an user input on your server.

I don't know if I got you right, but do something like that:

```
var filename string
switch selection := request.FormValue("select_fruit"); selection {
case "orange", "pear", "grape":
    filename = selection+".txt"
default:
    filename = "fruit.txt"
}

if data, err := config.ViewConfiguration(filename); err != nil {
    //TODO handle error
} else {
    //TODO do stuff
}
```